# Xamarin - working with VectorDrawable in Imageview and Edittext

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-vectordrawable

I face issue to apply vectordrawable at my imageView and Edittext

here is my tries to fix the issue

***First*** I am using [Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents/) Version 23.4.0

***Second*** I add `AppCompatDelegate.CompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled = true;` in onCreate of my Application

```
public class MyApplication : Application
    {


        public MyApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownerShip) : base(handle, ownerShip)
        {
            Log.Debug("App", "I am in oncreate application");
        }
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            AppCompatDelegate.CompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled = true;

        }

}
```

***Third *** using`AppCompatActivity`  to make sure my activity used [AppCompatImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html) instead of normal `ImageView` and try set drawable manually but it return with null (I dont know why this happen )

```
 [Activity( Label = "Activity1", Theme = "@style/AppTheme")]
    public class Activity1 : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.test);

            ImageView testImage = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageViewTest);

            Drawable drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.Create(Resources, Resource.Drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp, null);
            testImage.SetImageDrawable(drawable);

        }
    }
```

***Fourth*** in my project .csproj I add  build tools version 23.0.3 
`<AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>23.0.3</AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>`

here is my full file content

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>23.0.3</AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>
    <AndroidDesignerPreferredDevice>Nexus 4</AndroidDesignerPreferredDevice>
    <SelectedDevice>Nexus_5_API_21_x86</SelectedDevice>
    <AndroidDesignerPreferredTheme>Theme.DeviceDefault</AndroidDesignerPreferredTheme>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**Fifth** I reference my vector image `app:srcCompat`

but it still not working any one could help me fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

I fix first half of my issue Simplly update to

```
Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable Version 23.4.0.1
```

make sure you reference your vector images by this way `app:srcCompat`

related to EditText Image I think you cant set it from xml you need to use it via code here is the method

```
SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom);
```

in my case I used leftdrawable so my method look like

```
SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Resource.Drawable.MyDrawable, 0, 0, 0);
```

hope this help any one face same issue

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Forget the **Old Solution**. Just update to the latest Verison of Xamarin (Xamarin.Android   7.2.0.7) and the latest version of the support libs (25.3.1).

---

## Old Solution:

Downgrade to Xamarin 4.2.0.680, use only the support libs version 23.3.0 (Latest stable 24.2.1 crashes on Android 4.4.4 but works on Android 6)

Also ensure this:

Put this static constructor in your Activity:

```
static Activity1()
{
   AppCompatDelegate.CompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled = true;
}
```

Or add `AppCompatDelegate.CompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled = true;` to your [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class´ `OnCreate` method.

`<AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>` in your project shouldn't be nessessary anymore.

Use `app:srcCompat`, like you already do.

Have a look at the Dependencies of each support lib at [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/23.3.0)

I have:

- Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll 23.3.0
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.dll 23.3.0
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v14.Preference.dll 23.3.0
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll 23.3.0
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll 23.3.0
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Preference.dll 23.3.0
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll 23.3.0
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.dll 23.3.0

Also make shure you reference `Java.Interop.dll`

Try out another vector drawable, for example from [Material Design Icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/) (Click on an icon, chose *Icon Package*, *.XML Vector Drawable*).